# How to bind data from one sheet row till end of the row into combobox using macro

Tags: excel, vba

please provide me a solution for this issue.
I am new to macro I am unable to do this operation.

I tried this code

```
Sub BindCombo()
Dim Last

Last = Sheets("Defect Dump").Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row
With ComboBox1
For Row = 2 To Last
.AddItem Sheets("Defect Dump").Cells(Row, 1)
Next Row
End With

End Sub
```

But this code shows object error

Comment: where exactly you have you error, which line?? Are you sure that 'Defect Dump' sheet exists and there is no misspelling??

Comment: The dropdown is another sheet"project sheet". From "defect Dump" sheet only i have to get the data and populate the value in the "project sheet" where the dropdown control is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an object reference to the `ComboBox`

try this

```
Sub BindCombo()
    Dim Last As Long, rw As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cb As ComboBox

    Set sh = Sheets("Defect Dump")
    Last = sh.Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    ' get Combobox on "project sheet" sheet
    Set cb = Sheets("project sheet").Shapes("ComboBox1").DrawingObject.Object
    With cb
        .Clear ' remove any existing items
        For rw = 2 To Last
            .AddItem sh.Cells(rw, 1)
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: hi Chris 
The combo box is in another sheet "project sheet".so how to link from one sheet to another sheet

Comment: I am getting an error"The item with the specified name wasn't found". Can u pls help

Comment: The dropdown is another sheet"project sheet". From "defect Dump" sheet only i have to get the data and populate the value in the "project sheet" where the dropdown control is added

Comment: Set cb = sh.Shapes("ComboBox1").DrawingObject.Object

Comment: can u pls give me a code snippet. i m new to macro so lot of functionality i dnt know

Comment: have you tried the edited version with `Set cb = Sheets("project sheet").Shapes("ComboBox1").DrawingObject.Object` ?  if so, what error do you get?

Comment: its showing unspecified error in this line" .AddItem sh.Cells(rw, 1)"

Comment: Set sh = Sheets("Defect Dump")
    Last = sh.Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row
Is this code is correct for getting the value of the particular column?

Comment: update your question with a short sample of your data, and indicate which values you want to put in the combo box

Comment: first i have data which is in the defect dump sheet columnA. what i need is i need to get the values of the particular column from a2 to end of the column stil empty values. that set of data need to be binded in the combo box which is in the project sheet

Comment: So why are you using `Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row`? shouldn't that be `Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row`?

Comment: thanks for the help
i can able to get the data in th dropdown. 
can u provide a code how to write for dropdown change event based on the value selected the data should be populated in another sheet

Comment: have a go yourself.  if you get stuck ask a new question.  BTW, if this has answered your question, you should accept it (click the tick)